# How to Schedule a task so that it executes in any condition in android

Tags: java, android, service

I am working on an Android Project that requires some tasks to be run at some times. The task to be performed is selected by user along with the time at which it needs to be performed. I have tried using  `BroadcastReceiver` and `AlarmManager` to perform the task at its time. But the problem is - **task stop performing when the app is closed**. Below is my code for `BroadcastReceiver` and `AlarmManager` classes.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Alarm received");

        // perform the task here using the values received by Intent
    }
}
```

I called this `AlarmReceiver` using `AlarmManager` as:

```
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("foo", foo);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("bar", bar);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

where `date.getTime()` is the time at which the task is to be performed.

All works fine. But **I want a solution that makes this work even if the app is force closed.**
I also want the solution to be able to perform multiple such tasks scheduled one after another or even for the next day. *IF POSSIBLE*

Note: I thought of using a `Service` class to accomplish this but couldn't figure out how to write the `Service` class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a forced closed will allow tasks to keep working. You could however register a BroadcastReceiver on system events to let the application come back to live (e.g. android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED and QUICKBOOT_POWERON)

For tasks you should really look at the WorkManager library.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/package-summary and https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager
It does a lot of work for you to listen to system events. It offers a PeriodicWorkRequest and OneTimeWorkRequest for repetitive and single tasks.

Latest lib: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0

```
import androidx.work.Constraints
import androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE
import androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest
import androidx.work.WorkManager

    private fun startTask(interval: Int) {
        val flexInterval = when {
            interval > 200 -> 30L
            interval > 59 -> 15L
            else -> 5L
        }
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder().setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true).build()

        val fileFinderWork = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            FileFindWorker::class.java,
            interval.toLong(), TimeUnit.MINUTES,
            flexInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES
        ).setConstraints(constraints).addTag(WORK_TAG).build()

        Logger.e("Enqueueing file finder worker ($interval min.)")

        val manager: WorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(ctx)
        manager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(WORK_NAME, REPLACE, fileFinderWork)
   }
```

Or in Java

```java
import androidx.work.Constraints;
import androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy;
import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;

    private UUID startTask() {
        int interval = 99 /* Just a value from configuration */;
        TimeUnit unit;
        int flexInterval;

        if (interval % 60 == 0) {
            interval = interval / 60;
            unit = TimeUnit.HOURS;
        } else {
            unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES;
        }

        if (interval >= 240) {
            flexInterval = 30;
        } else if (interval >= 60) {
            flexInterval = 15;
        } else {
            flexInterval = 5;
        }

        final Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                .build();

        final PeriodicWorkRequest fileFinderWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                FileFindWorker.class, interval, unit, flexInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .addTag(WORK_TAG)
                .build();

        lastPeriodicUuid = fileFinderWork.getId();

        WorkManager manager = WorkManager.getInstance(ctx)
        manager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(WORK_NAME, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, fileFinderWork);

        return fileFinderWork.getId();
    }
```

Comment: I'll add the Java version ;)

Comment: that will be be much appreciated. Thanks